# Laravel add domains to controller routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes, laravel-routing

I have a Laravel App and a domain to access it. The Domain points to the public folder and executes the '/' route which then executes a certain method 'BaseController@index' in a controller.Now I want to add another domain. But this domain should execute another method 'AppController@run' (route can be '/app/run/.

How can I achieve this?

I created a vhost for this other domain that points directly to public/app/run. This works but the browser shows domain.com/app/run which I don't like.

So I think what I have do do is let this domain point to public and then in my routes file say that this domain shell execute 'AppController@run'

Or in the worst case it points to the '/' route and then inside the BaseController@index method I have to check what domain is accessing. But this seems not good to me.

Any ideas? I wonder why I can't find a lot on Google since this should not be only important to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, all vhosts should have set the document root to the `public` public directory, otherwise Laravel won't bootstrap correctly.

Then you can add specific routes for that domain. For example:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'seconddomain.com'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'AppController@run');
});
```

Now if you go to `seconddomain.com` `run()` in `AppController` will be called

Comment: Short and logical. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Framework 5.7.2

I wanted a separate domain for my API.

My solution was to edit the mapApiRoutes() in Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

```
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    //This is what we're changing to Route:domain('www.sub.domain.com')
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

and the function should look something like this:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::domain('www.sub.domain.com')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

You will also need to reconfigure your apache depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Hope this helps.